# Size of IPv4 Pools assigned to RIRs

Tags: ip-address, ipv4, iana

I downloaded the latest delegated File from the Ripe RIR.
[delegated file ripe](ftp://ftp.ripe.net/pub/stats/ripencc/delegated-ripencc-extended-latest)
There are lines like:

```
ripencc|AT|ipv4|194.246.96.0|256|19970714|assigned
ripencc|CH|ipv4|194.246.97.0|256|20040211|assigned
ripencc|PL|ipv4|194.246.98.0|256|20040211|assigned
ripencc|UA|ipv4|194.246.99.0|256|20040211|assigned
ripencc|FR|ipv4|194.246.101.0|256|20040211|assigned
ripencc|HU|ipv4|194.246.102.0|256|20040212|assigned
ripencc|UA|ipv4|194.246.104.0|512|20040202|assigned
ripencc|PL|ipv4|194.246.106.0|512|20040202|assigned
ripencc|GB|ipv4|194.246.108.0|512|20080415|assigned
ripencc|BG|ipv4|194.246.110.0|512|20040204|assigned
ripencc|RU|ipv4|194.246.112.0|512|20040204|assigned
ripencc|RU|ipv4|194.246.114.0|512|20090929|assigned
ripencc|UA|ipv4|194.246.116.0|512|20040206|assigned
ripencc|CH|ipv4|194.246.118.0|512|20040209|assigned
```

or from Africa:

```
afrinic|ZA|ipv4|41.0.0.0|2097152|20071126|allocated|F364712F
afrinic|EG|ipv4|41.32.0.0|1048576|20091105|allocated|F36B49FA
```

How do I know the size of an IP-Adress pool. I mean the start and end IP-address? 
And are only those pools used who have the value assigned?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: see that number after the IP? That's the block size. 194.246.104.0|512 is 194.246.104.0 -> 194.246.105.255, which is 512 IPs (edit: I can *not* type today for some reason)

Comment: There is a pretty detailed description of the contents of that file in ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/stats/RIR-Statistics-Exchange-Format.txt. Can you please indicate which part you have trouble reading/parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc B gave me the answer:
see that number after the IP? That's the block size. 194.246.104.0|512 is 194.246.104.0 -> 194.246.105.255, which is 512 IPs (edit: I can not type today for some reason)